# Windows 10 clients can't connect to HostAPD

Tags: linux, windows, wifi, hostapd

I have an access point running on a linux server.

I'm using hostapd 2.4 on ubuntu 16.04.

wifi adapter: Intel® Centrino® Advanced-N 6235

android, iphone, linux computers, and windows 7(don't have a windows 8 box to test with) and earlier windows can connect just fine. But Windows 10 systems can't.  I Think it may be related to this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3121002 (there was a eap error in the windows event log), Is there some additional configuration options to hostapd I can set to make this work.  I didn't think a radius server would be necessary for wpa-psk.

The windows 10 clients won't connect if I set hostapd as an open connection as well.

Here's my hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=hostname
channel=6
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=password
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set

```
wpa=2
```

this configuration worked for me

```
interface=wlan0
ssid=$SSID
hw_mode=g
wpa=2
ieee8021x=0
eap_server=0
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa_passphrase=$PASSWORD
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
channel=5
```